# Where can I find a plasma rifle/pistol in the Commonwealth?

Tags: fallout-4

I have always loved the Plasma weapons in Fallout, because who doesn't like turning things in to a pile of green goo? In Fallout 4 they are even more versatile because you can mod the same gun between all of the different types (pistol, rifle, heavy, etc). So... I would like to get my hands on them. Problem is they seem to be pretty rare.

Where are some locations where I can find any version of a plasma gun?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plasma weapons in Fallout 4 are relatively rare because of how powerful they are. You'll almost certainly not find one before level 20 and if you do you'll most likely be out of ammo for it with no way of getting more as the plasma cartridges are some of the most expensive ammunition in the game. Ultimately *random drops are random* and so you may find them anywhere, higher level enemies are far more likely to carry one than lower level enemies though.

You're far more likely to find a plasma pistol than any other form factor, but this can be upgraded into a rifle using the weapons bench as required, and to that end, there is normally a plasma pistol being stored inside the Mass Pike Tunnel West (near Diamond City), inside the room containing a steamer trunk with a Plasma Pistol inside.

The "best" plasma weapons in the game are the unique faction variants such as Experiment 18-A, which can be purchased from a synth vendor in the Institute, and the AX90 Fury or Sentinel's Plasmacaster, which can be purchased aboard the Prydwen.

Comment: Have an upvote, I had no idea I could upgrade the pistol into a rifle. I'll do that with Science!

Comment: @DavidYell Sure ignore that I put that into the question ;)  But Kalina.. is there really only that one pistol to be found in the game aside from Vendors? I was hopping that one webiste was wrong or just lacking more information.

Comment: Well random drops are random... I haven't been to that location to pick it up, I've found mine from random drops. You can apparently always get one in that specific location and thus I figured that would be a more useful answer than "random drops are random"

Comment: @james I gave you an upvote too!

Comment: I am just looking for any way to get these types of guns. I would not really want to modify the unique ones and I have not seen anything drop them as of yet (though I will admit I have not hunted down the Brother hood of Steel people as they are on my side so far... though they seem to prefer laser rifles so probably not helpful)

Comment: I have found a few plasma pistols and a rifle while clearing Vault 95 (dropped from enemies, mainly Gunners members). The place was rough though, those damn Assaultrons are no joke.

Comment: I will add, you can find unique pipe pistols+variants that do an additional amount of plasma damage. I found one that does an additional 10 plasma damage and turned it into a sniper rifle. The majority of one-shot kills end with the target turning into a pile of green goop.

Comment: @James Why not modify them? There's no risk of "damaging" them, and you can always put them back to the default configuration if the mood strikes you. In reality, the "unique" trait is a weapon component like any other. There are game mods (for PC, of course) that expose them and let you change them like any other part.

Comment: @T.J.L. Personal preference is all, I like keeping the unique guns unique? Hehe. Id rather have some randoms that I can just screw around with.

Answer (score 1):

I bought an Incendiary Automatic Plasma Rifle from trader slightly north of a ruined town that always has a Yuo Guai resting in the center. She has a metal trailer just a few steps into the woods. I forgot the name of the town, but it's directly north of Fallon's Department Store and south of from Diamond City. It's an automatic so it pretty weak but I'm planning on modding the hell out of it once I get my hands on another one(and some ammo).

Comment: Trader inventories are random.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've found most other types of weapon and ammo just by scavenging in the wasteland, plasma weapons do seem rarer and I ended up paying for them.

The weapon vendors [Cricket](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cricket) and [Arturo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arturo_Rodriguez) often have plasma weapons for sale. Cricket can sometimes be found near Diamond City, and Arturo is always in Diamond City Market during the day.

Answer (score -2):

I just found a enraging plasma rifle in faneul hall from a legandery mutant dog whilst doing the gilded grasshopper mission

Comment: All legendary loot is random. This answer is not helpful.